# Standardisation of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Knowing that random vector
$$
\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\textbf{Y}-\mu) \sim N(0, I)
$$
what is the distribution of random variable
$$
(\textbf{Y}-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\textbf{Y}-\mu)
$$
where random vector $\textbf{Y}$ has a normal distribution with positive semidefinite covariance matrix $\Sigma$ and expected value vector $\mu$?

My attempt was to
$$
(\textbf{Y}-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(\textbf{Y}-\mu) = (\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\textbf{Y}-\mu))^T(\Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}(\textbf{Y}-\mu)) = \text{?}
$$

I know that both brackets are $N(0, I)$ but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: In $(\textbf{Y}-\mu)^T\Sigma(\textbf{Y}-\mu)$, shouldn't it be $\Sigma^{-1}$? Then, your attempt is in the right direction, and you get $\chi^2_n$.

Comment: @zhoraster You're right - it is $\Sigma^{-1}$. Are there any more steps required to conclude it is $\chi_n^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\Sigma^{-\frac12}({\bf Y}-\mu)$ has $N(0,I)$ distribution then it has the same distribution as ${\bf Z}:=(Z_1,Z_2,\ldots,Z_n)^T$ where the $Z_i$'s are independent standard normal random variables. It follows that $(\Sigma^{-\frac12}({\bf Y}-\mu))^T(\Sigma^{-\frac12}({\bf Y}-\mu))$ has the same distribution as ${\bf Z}^T{\bf Z} = \sum_i Z_i^2$. But the sum of squares of $n$ standard normal variables has the $\chi^2_n$ distribution.